# Filter Google Sheets' pivot table by comparison with column

Tags: filter, google-sheets, pivot

I want to filter a pivot table in the following set up:

My Table:

```
Key Value1  Value2
1   23      a
2   33      b
3   1       c
4   5       d
```

My pivot table (simplified):

```
Key SUM of Value1   COUNTA of Value2
1   23              1
2   33              1
3   1               1
4   5               1
Grand Total 62      4
```

I now want to filter the pivot table by the values in this list:

```
Keys
1
2
4
```

So the resulting pivot table should look like this:

```
Key SUM of Value1   COUNTA of Value2
1   23              1
2   33              1
4   5               1
Grand Total 61      3
```

I thought this should be possible by using a custom formula in the pivot filter but it seems I have no way of using the current cell in the pivot e.g. to make a lookup.

I created a simple example of this setup here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GlQDYtW8v8ri5L68RhryTZxwTikV_NXZQlccSI6_7pU/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

paste this formula in **Filters!B1**:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1:A, Table!A1:C, {2,3}, 0), ))
```

[image: 0]

and create a resulting pivot table from there:

[image]

**[demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cQTrPZfv4Be2maePb1kK5l6C4UQQb1ZfDOEOUdqqbQc/edit#gid=253592338)**

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Thats a nice workaround. It does require creating an additional table though. If I wanted to make this more reusable (e.g. applying the same filtering conditions to multiple tables for multiple pivots) is there a way to that?

Comment: well you can clone A column to D column with ={A1:A} and then use vlookup from D column ad construct your next pivot table from D:F etc.